# Inner foreach always has last iteration of outer foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following `foreach` loop (with an inner `foreach` loop):

```
foreach ($options_default as $key=>$value) {
        foreach ($option_names as $option_name_key=>$option_name_value){
            $temp = array($key=>$value);
            update_option($option_name_value, $temp);
            unset($temp);   
        }
    }
```

This loop is iterating through these two arrays:

```
    $option_names = array (
                'API_URL'=>'api-url',
                'API_CDN_URL'=>'cdn-url',
                'API_USERNAME'=> 'api-username'
    );

    $options_default = array (
            'api_url' => 'url1', 
            'cdn_url' => 'url2', 
            'api_username' => 'test', 
);
```

However, the value of `$temp` is always set to the last key/value pair from the `$options_default` array. Could anyone suggest what the issue might be here?

-> expected output

So the loop will make these three calls to update option (lets imagine I'm just passing $value as the second argument for ease):

```
update_option(api-url,url1);
update_option(cdn-url,url2);
update_option(api-username,test);
```

Comment: Change `'API_USERNAME'= 'api-username'` to `'API_USERNAME' => 'api-username'`... there is an syntax error... :)

Comment: what is your expected outcome? its confusing what you asked?

Comment: @KaushaMehta i think that is typo mistake

Comment: @KaushaMehta thanks for that, that's not the answer unfortunately though, it was just an error on here.

Comment: Your foreach loops are working fine. Why do you think that `$temp` is always `Array ( [api_username] => test )`?

Comment: @simon It's writing something to a database, the value is always set to this key.

Comment: How does your `update_option` function look like? I guess the problem is there

Comment: shouldn't `$temp = array($key => $option_name_value)` be like this ?

Comment: @simon It's a built in WordPress function, there's no issue with this though

Comment: I see. Describe your expected result, I think I misunderstood what you want.

Comment: @simon thanks, I've made an edit to show the expected output

Comment: It won't make three calls, it'll make ***nine***.

Answer (score 0):

Think again about your construct of `foreach` loops and why it doesn't do what you want it to. You are currently looping three times over `$option_names` which results in nine calls to `update_option`. Also take a look at the parameters of `update_option`. In your code, you're passing two arguments to it: a string and an array. But what you obviously want is two strings.

You could use a [MultipleIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) in combination with [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) for this task:

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($option_names));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($options_default));

foreach ($iterator as $values) {
    update_option($values[0], $values[1]);
}
```

Hope this helps